# Python Iterating an Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, random

I have been trying to iterate through an array.

below is the code.

```
x = ['lemon', 'tea', 'water', ]

def randomShuffle (arr,n):
    from random import choices
    newList=[]


    for item in arr:
        r=choices(arr, k=n)

        if r.count(item) <= 2:
            newList.append(item)

        return (newList)
```

i would like to know the logic for writing it please.

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop: if every item is to appear twice, then teh resulting array should be twice the length of the input one.
And of course check not to add the same item more than twice in the result ;)

Choices return a list of size 1, so I use [0] to get the element

```py
xx = ["a", "b", "c"]

def my_function(x):
    res = []
    while len(res) < len(x) * 2:
        c = choices(x)[0]
        if res.count(c) < 2:
            res.append(c)
    return res

my_function(xx)
> ['c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
my_function(xx)
> ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That is exactly what's needed